# Submitting form containing <keygen> using POST in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, http-post, spkac

For the first time I have oi submit a form in AngularJS using POST Http Request, in particular this form contains a keygen element that generates a key as follows:

```
<keygen id="spkac" name="spkac" challenge="randomchars" keytype="rsa" hidden>
```

The spkac element gets to the server always empty, plus I think I am not passing the data from the form to the POST in the correct way, so my questions are:

1. How to set spkac as parameter part of the form?
2. Is this the correct way to pass the data to the POST in AngularJS?

**EDIT** **Form:**

```
    <form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" method="POST" ng-submit="create()">
                <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="mtest">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Account name" name="webid" ng-model="account.webid" ng-focus="isFocused" ng-blur="isFocused = false"><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" name="name" ng-model="account.name"><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="account.email"><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Picture URL" name="pictureURL" ng-model="account.pictureURL"><br>

                <keygen id="spkac" name="spkac" challenge="randomchars" keytype="rsa" hidden>

                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

**EDIT** **HTTP Request:**

```
$scope.signupForm = {};
$scope.create = function () {
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "Creating...";
        var uri = "https://" + "...";
        //setting spkac part of the form's parameters
        $scope.account.spkac = document.getElementById("spkac");

        $http({
          method: 'POST', 
          url: uri,
          data: $.param($scope.account),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/x-x509-user-cert'
          },
          withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers) {
          if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
              //Account created 
          }
        }).
```

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass the entire form as data to post request. Instead you should pass the models associated with the field to `data` config of post request.

```
data : $.param({
  webid : webid,
  name : name,
  email : email
  ...
})
```

Since the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You will get all the model values as form parameters in your back-end service.

Comment: I have edited the parameters to be attributes of an account object (check EDIT sections). Now, is passing the object this way the same thing as you suggested? $.param($scope.account)

Comment: Still having the REST Resource receiving @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")?

Comment: It gives me error on the ":" and doesn't accept the format from the fist place

Comment: Now tried your format (bulding the object in the data filed instead) it gives teh same result: which is the browser crashes!

Comment: Sorry, try **$.param({account : $scope.account})**

Comment: Building it (as you suggested in the answer) or having the account object (like your suggestion in the last comment) both kinda crashed the request, more precisly it happens like the screen shot (check EDIT 2).

Comment: Remove 1st & 4th line from create function. It is not necessary at all.

Comment: The spkac deosn't appear in the account object, so I am forcing it.

Comment: If I remove it it deosn't act weired anymroe. But I get this: "Failed 500 Your request could not be processed. Either no WebID or no SPKAC value was provided".

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

So preparing an HTTP Request to do that doesn't work for some reason. Instead the form action needs to be set and form submitted straight away in order to send the keygen with it. Here the solution:

in the **Template** the action is parametrical:

```
    <form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" method="POST" action="{{actionUrl}}">
     ...
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" ng-click="completeForm()">
```

and the **Controller** sets the action and submits the form as follows:

```
$scope.completeForm = function () {
        $scope.actionUrl = "https://" + document.getElementById("username").value + "...";
        document.getElementById("signupForm").submit();     
};
```